# Get max value from multiple columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I was trying to convert the below query to sqlalchemy:

```
SELECT
   addr_idn,
   (SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
      FROM (VALUES (crt_dt),(upd_dt)) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate))
   AS LastUpdateDate
FROM (
select a. addr_idn,a.crt_dt crt_dt , b.upd_dt upd_dt
from emp_addr
where emp_addr.addr_idn = 1
) a
```

but I am not able to convert this into sqlalchemy. Please help me out to convert this query.

Comment: What particular part are you having trouble with? Are you using the ORM or the Core? What do your model or table definitions look like?

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy ORM. I have problem in getting the max from multiple columns which comes from the subquery

Comment: Then please provide your model and your attempt at forming the query in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit To : Mike Bayer

The hard part here is the "FROM VALUES" which is not built-in to
SQLAlchemy.

There is a recipe at

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PGValues

that will show how to build a "values()" function that will give you
the VALUES() expression you're looking for.

> --
> SQLAlchemy -
> The Python SQL Toolkit and Object Relational Mapper
>
> http://www.sqlalchemy.org/
>
> To post example code, please provide an MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and
> Verifiable Example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a full
> description.